# SQL joining 2 tables to fill blank fields

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

I have 2 tables and want to join them.
Table1:

| Period | Sale |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 30$ |
| Q2 | 40$ |

Table2:

| Period | Sale |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 10$ |
| Q2 |  |

as you can see, Table2 has no Sale-Value in Q2. Now I want to fill this field with the field of Table1. So, basically, if period=period and sale is empty, take the value of the other table.

i tried
select Table1.Period, Table1.Sale, Table2.Period, Table2.Sale
from Table2 left outer join Table1
on Table1.Period=Table2.Period

the result is:

| Table2.Period | Table2.Sale | Table1.Period | Table1.Sale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | 10$ | Q1 | 30$ |
| Q2 |  | Q2 | 40$ |

But what I expect is:

| Table2.Period | Table2.Sale |
| --- | --- |
| Q1 | 10$ |
| Q2 | 40$ |

Q2 of Table2 was empty before, so it took the Q2 value of Table1...

how can I achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need an `UPDATE`, not a `SELECT`.  Assuming t2.Sale is `NULL`, you can use the statement below.

```
UPDATE Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.Period = t1.Period
SET t1.Sale = t2.Sale
WHERE t2.Sale IS NULL
```

Comment: doesnt work for me, it says syntax error

Comment: Are you sure you are using `mysql`?

Comment: i am using microsoft access

Comment: Then why do you put `mysql` as your tag on your question???  This is the problem if you don't tag your question properly.  My query works just find in `MySQL`.  But you don't use MySQL.

Comment: Please remove the `mysql` tag, and replace it with `access` or something.